# how does "not earlier than in [time period]" sound to a native English speaker?

Tags: phrase-usage

I noticed that this pattern is often used by English speaking Russians. How does it sound to a native English speaker? Usage example: "I could do that, but not earlier than in a month".

Comment: It's fine, although I would say "*no* earlier than in *one* month".  Also *sooner* sounds a little better to me, *"I could finish it, but it'll be no sooner than one month (from today)"*

Comment: More fluent would also be "...but not in *less* than a month."  *Earlier* is usually used mean "before a specific point in time", and "a month" isn't a specific point, so *earlier* is a little awkward.

Answer (score 2):

> "I could do that, but not earlier than in a month."

Most of the time, I think I would change the perspective, and get rid of the negative:

> "I could do that, but it would take **at least** a month."

Otherwise, I might use *sooner* rather than *earlier*:

> "I could do that, but no sooner than a month from now."

Comment: The OP's version doesn't seem *ungrammatical* to me, but I do like your versions much better.

Comment: @snailboat - I agree with what you say about grammaticality. However, when the OP asked "How does it sound?" I assumed that meant "How _natural_ does it sound?" and I tried to supply some more natural alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

It is unnatural, if not ungrammatical. "Earlier" is comparing to another time, but "in a month" is not a time, it's a *property* that a time could have. You can say "faster than in a month", or "earlier than a month from now".